# how to add a new c# file to a project using dotnet-cli

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, dotnet-cli

I'm learning how to use dotnet-cli with VSCode. I've seen many commands on how to create solution, projects, add reference to projects... but I don't see anywhere in the documentation how to add a file. If remember, in RubyOnRails it was possible to add file from the command line.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Even I have not encountered any documentation for this. I prefer it from vs code UI.

Comment: I see. It's those boilerplate code, such as using statement, namespace, class definition, that I'm after. However, if there's none, that's ok too. I'll just write them myself.

Comment: Are you wanting simply to create a new file or are you wanting to create a file with content that follows a certain template?

Answer (score 10):

Not that I know of (I was also researching that topic) but I found helpful extension for VS code called C# Extensions by jchannon, which helps you create classes and interfaces with correct namespace by right-clicking the folder in VS code explorer and selecting to create C# class or C# interface.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears this extension is on longer under development.

Comment: It is, but by a different author (see [here](https://github.com/KreativJos/csharpextensions)). Works well.

Answer (score 8):

If you’re after plain old C# classes then yeah, I’m not aware of *cli* support. However, VS Code can create classes with the “right” namespaces by right-clicking on a folder and selecting Add new class (or somesuch).

However the dotnet aspnet-codegenerator can create boilerplate classes for various elements of an MVC application. [Here](http://jamesirl.com/posts/dotnet-code-scaffolding) is a discussion.

Comment: Note that you need the extension "C# Extensions" installed for the right-click options to show up.

Comment: it would be great to have a mouse-free option.  Does the "C# Extensions" vscode extension have robust keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: It is no longer under development.

Answer (score 6):

just type

> `new-item YourCSharpFileName.cs`

*i know this is not your point but; this simple answer must stay here*

this **powershell command** doesn't create a **templated** csharp class but; if you like or find easier to add a new file just by **typing**. powershell, command prompt or any terminal... it could be very helpfull. add your file than configure the others(namespace, usings...)

additionaly for git bash use `touch YourFileName.cs`

i hope this help someone. if anything wrong please comment me.

Comment: This generates the files yes but it does not generate a namespace nor a corresponding class inside the respective files. Nice though.

Comment: thank you for your comment @Nulle. i have only pointed out easyness of the terminal  creating file. snippets could be used for the class or interface or controller or other... c sharp types.

Answer (score 4):

Just add the file in the same directory or sub-directory then build the project using Core CLI, it will be added. 
As per the Core CLI documentation by default all the source files are included in the build, without being added into the project files, though there are option available to override this default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has an UX that allows you to right-click a project or a folder underneath a project and open a context window. Selecting Add brings up a modal that allows you to select a file template. This intelligently adds the corresponding file to the location specified, adding a calculated namespace and default `using` statements that are typical for that file type. These item templates are backed by `.vstemplate` files and complemented by a file of that type. For example, for a C# class, there is a Class folder with a Class.cs file and a Class.vstemplate file. The former is a template for a C# file, the latter is an XML-based file that describes the template, per the XML namespace described [here](http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005). This is a starting point.

According to [Tutorial: Create a project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-project-template) for `dotnet new`,

> With .NET Core, you can create and deploy templates that generate projects, **files**, even resources. This tutorial is part two of a series that teaches you how to create, install, and uninstall, templates for use with the `dotnet new` command. [emphasis added]

This blog post, [How to create your own template for dotnet new](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-create-your-own-templates-for-dotnet-new/), has some examples how to add [replaceable parameters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-create-your-own-templates-for-dotnet-new/#how-to-create-a-template-with-replaceable-parameters) and [optional content](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-create-your-own-templates-for-dotnet-new/#add-optional-content), which would be good for adding namespaces, class names, class keywords, etc.

Based on this information, my next step would be to try and create some `dotnet new` file templates. After the basics of creating a file, I would then experiment with how to make them smarter, like these VS Templates, using replaceable parameters and optional content.

Answer (score 1):

**dotnet new** provides many templates like mvc, webapp, classlib, etc. but doesn't provide templates for **class**, **interface**, **struct**, etc. ...

I searched and found that we can install these templates using command

```
dotnet new -i Yae.Templates::0.0.2
```

and then you can use command in your preferred directory

```
dotnet new class -t <nameOfClass_without_extension_.cs>
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the template first

```
dotnet new --install Yae.Templates
```

Then you can use

```
dotnet new class -t filename -o foldername
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried `dotnet new class -h` to see the available options.

So, we can use something simple like this `dotnet new class -n users`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used to use the plugin C# Extensions which is no longer under development. Today I found a replacement extension for the new class/interface functionality called "C# Stretch": https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jacokok.csharp-stretch

Its a context-menu item in the file explorer allowing you to type in a class name. It produces a C# file with an empty class with the namespace declared in the new file-scoped manner. The nesting namespace format is available as an option in settings.

Answer (score 0):

Install the template first:

```
dotnet new --install Yae.Templates
```

To create new class file:

```
dotnet new class -ty "YourClassName"
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with:

```
dotnet new class --name MyClass --language C#
```

Which produced a *.cs file containing:

```
namespace MyNamespace;

public class MyClass
{

}
```

I am using .NET SDK 8.0.201 and the latest dotnet CLI. I noticed that the namespace is always the same as the project namespace rather than the current folder namespace.   You will need to set the namespace to your preference.